# How to work with locale-file for language settings and simple-prefs for options window with add-on builder

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an add-on with the Mozilla Add-on Builder.
There are 3 problems that I cannot find a solution for:

1. To be able to provide a user dependent language I have to add properties-files to the locale-file - i.e. en-US.properties. But how do I implement this using the Add-on Builder?
   I can use the ln10-module but I have no clue how to create the property files since the only visible (to me) folders are `lib`, `data` and `libraries` - and not `locale`.
2. Other extensions that I have installed open a small preferences-window when I click on "Options" in the Add-on Manager. But when I use the module `simple-prefs` the prefs are displayed on the same site as all other informations displayed when clicking on "more". How do I achieve a small seperate "window" for my prefs? And are there othere options for me to style it besides the spartanic "type"-"value"-thingy?
3. I know how to use Erik Vold's `toolbarbutton` module but how can I achieve such nice options windows that open when I click i.e. on the toolbar icon or on "options" in the menu like other extensions?

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to pack three unrelated question into one. Even if you get all three questions answered, the answers are unlikely to cover all topics equally well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to get rid of the basic misconception first. There are two very different types of Firefox extensions: the classic XUL-based extensions and the extensions based on the Add-on SDK. The Add-on Builder works with the latter, pretty much all of the extensions documentation on [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/) applies to the former.

> I can use the ln10-module but I have no clue how to create the property files since the only visible (to me) folders are lib, data and libraries - and not locale.

It seems that the Add-on Builder doesn't support localized add-ons yet. You can [download the Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/developers/builder) and build your extension from the command line - this will give you more options.

> Other extensions that I have installed open a small preferences-window when I click on "Options" in the Add-on Manager.

These are XUL-based extensions. The Add-on SDK doesn't support opening new windows, merely [panels](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.9/packages/addon-kit/panel.html). However, even opening a panel for the add-on options would require some very creative hacking.

> how can I achieve such nice options windows that open when I click i.e. on the toolbar icon or on "options" in the menu like other extensions?

Same here - the Add-on SDK supports HTML-based panels, no real (XUL-based) application windows.